# Accessing DocumentDb from Azure Functions with dynamic DocumentId

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-functions

Here is my **function.json:**

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "name": "req"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "inputDocument",
      "databaseName": "MyDb",
      "collectionName": "MyCol",
      "partitionKey": "main",
      "id": "{documentId}",
      "connection": "MyDocDbConnStr",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ],
  "disabled": false
}
```

And here is my **run.csx:**

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log, dynamic inputDocument)
{

    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"doc title is {inputDocument.title}");
}
```

Everything works fine if I define a fixed value for my document id in config.

But when I want to use a dynamic document id and use **{documentId}**, I get this error:

```
No binding parameter exists for 'documentId'.
```

My **post data** is:

```
{
    "documentId": "002"
}
```

How can I send **DocumentId** to my Azure Function and get associated item from DocumentDb?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To use custom parameters in C# binding expressions, those properties must be defined on the type your trigger input is bound to. Since you want to bind to `documentId` from the input payload, we define an `Input` POCO with a corresponding `DocumentId` property. Here's a working sample:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Input
{
    public string DocumentId { get; set; }
}

public static HttpResponseMessage Run(Input input, 
              HttpRequestMessage req, dynamic document, TraceWriter log)
{
    if (document != null)
    {
        log.Info($"DocumentId: {document.text}");
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
    else
    {
        return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
}
```

And here is the corresponding function.json:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "webHookType": "genericJson",
      "name": "input"
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "documentDB",
      "name": "document",
      "databaseName": "ItemDb",
      "collectionName": "ItemCollection",
      "id": "{documentId}",
      "connection": "test_DOCUMENTDB",
      "direction": "in"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have tested a code similar to this (input payload, poco object,...) but got some errors. I'll test it again and let you now if this worked or not. Used this sample: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/dev/sample/WebHook-Generic-CSharp/run.csx

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked perfectly. Using dynamic object raised error but using POCO worked, also adding input param to function.json made this work (I think I made some mistakes last time and this time added this carefully)

Answer (score 1):

A solution could be to parse the post data yourself. Something like this:

```
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, $"doc title is {data.documentId}");
}
```

Then if you have the documentId, you can use the .NET Client SDK for DocumentDb or the REST API just like you would from a Console App.

Comment: Thank you. I'm aware of this solution, but this looks like the hard way. Any other way to bind documentId?